# How to provide keytab for Spark job through code instead of spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, kerberos

I have a situation where I need to set the keytab and principal for a Java Spark job to access HBase through code. Using the keytab and principal options in the spark-submit works but I need to do this through code. Using the following options does not seem to work. I get a connnection closed exception with option 3 and `client cannot authenticate via:[token, kerberos]` error with the first two. The third option seems close but not sure why the connection gets closed.

```
sparkconf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Hbase With Spark")
        .set("spark.kerberos.principal", principalValue)
        .set("spark.kerberos.keytab", keytabFile);
```

---

Option 2:

```
sparkconf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Hbase With Spark")
        .set("spark.yarn.principal", principalValue)
        .set("spark.yarn.keytab", keytabFile);
```

Option 3:

```
conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("hbase.master.keytab.file",keytabFile)
conf.set("hbase.regionserver.keytab.file",keytabFile);
UserGroupInformation ugi;
ugi = UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser();
ugi.setConfiguration(conf);
ugi.loginUserFromKeytab(principalValue, keytabFile);
ugi.getLoginUser().doAs((new PrivilegedExceptionAction<SQLContext>() {
                    public SQLContext run() throws Exception {
                        
                        sparkconf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Hbase With Spark");
                        jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkconf);
                        sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(jsc);  
Dataset<Row> dfEmp = sqlContext.read().format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark")
                                .option("hbase.columns.mapping", sqlMapping)
                                .option("hbase.table", "employee").load();
// This is useful when issuing SQL text queries directly against the sqlContext object.
                        dfEmp.registerTempTable("empdata");  
                        dfEmp.show();
                        return sqlContext;
                    }
                }));
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't. For HBase, **each executor** has to manage its own Kerberos authentication, but you have no easy way to handle Kerberos in custom code on executor startup.

Comment: The native Spark way of handling Kerberos auth... is in the "client", i.e. **_before_** starting the driver (and executors). The Spark client connects to HDFS + optionally Hive Metastore + optionally HBase Master, authenticates with Kerberos _(not necessarily from a keytab - a TGT in the cache is enough)_, retrieves from each a **delegation token** that is valid for a few hours, passes the token(s) to the driver that passes it to the executors at startup time. For long-running jobs, the driver has to periodicaly re-authenticate to get new tokens, and for that it needs to be passed the keytab